# Wordpress list pages with children

Tags: wordpress

Hi guys this looks doable but I cant quite figure it out. I have a lists of pages in wordpress

```
Page1
Page2
Page3
Page4
```

when you are on a page need to display it's children but only it's children and not the children of the other pages (which all have children)

```
Page1
Page2
    -child1
    -child2
    -child3
        --grandchild1
        --grandchild2
    -child4
Page3
Page4
```

I have checked the codex but I don't think it does this?
Can anyone help?

Thanks
Jamie

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [wp_list_pages('childof=$parentPageID');](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this with [`get_page_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children).  It takes a parent page ID and an array of all pages and returns a filtered array that only contains the pages that are children of the parent page.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. These examples worked but now I need to another layer to the navigation so it looks like this:

Parent1
-Page1
-Page2
    --child1
    --child2
    -child3
        ---grandchild1
        ----grandchild2
    --child4
-Page3
-Page4
Parent2
Parent3

If I list the current pages children, because now all pages (page1 page2 page3 etc) are a child of parent 1, all of their pages get listed instead of just page 2's children